# Bitwise complement operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Can you guys please explain the below program

```
int main() 
{   
 int max = ~0; 
 printf("%d\n",max);    
 return 0; 
}
```

AFAIK ~ will flip the bits. In this case i.e ~0 will set all the bits into 1. So max variable should contain MAX value but I am getting o/p as -1. So can anyone here please tell me why I am getting o/p as -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why did you expect to obtain the "max value"? In 2's-complement signed representation all-1 bit pattern stands for `-1`. It is just the way it is.

Maximum value in 2's-complement signed representation is represented by `01111...1` bit pattern (i.e the first bit is `0`). What you got is `1111...1`, which is obviously negative since the very first bit - sign bit - is `1`.

If you want an example where complemented zero produces a "max value", use *unsigned* representation

```
int main() {   
  unsigned max = ~0u; 
  printf("%u\n", max);    
}
```

Comment: Note that both the type of the variable/expression **and** the format specifier (`%u`) must agree for this to work, too. If they're mismatched you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct output since you are using the `int` data type which is signed.  You need to read about two's complement negative representation.  All one bits is not the maximum negative value, it is -1 as your program outputs.  Maximum negative signed value is most significant bit set and all the remaining bits zero, 0x80000000 in the 32-bit case.  Maximum positive signed value is 0x7fffffff in the 32-bit case.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers have already covered the reason behind `~0` having value -1.

If you are looking for max integer value, then you can include the limits.h library and use the constants declared in that library

`INT_MAX` gives you the maximum signed integer value.
`UINT_MAX` gives you the maximum unsigned integer value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
printf( "Max signed int value: %d \n", INT_MAX);
printf("Max unsigned int value: %u \n", UINT_MAX );
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was a long time ago, but for posterity's sake:
It might help you to see it better if you print ~0 as both int and hex as follows:

```
printf("compliment of zero %d\n", (~0));
printf("compliment of zero 0x%x\n", (~0));
```

Output:
Compliment of zero -1 
Compliment of zero 0xffffffff