# I am not getting the answer I expect using the Bitwise NOT operator. Would appreciate some help

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am working though a C++ book trying to learn some things.  I am stuck on one thing, the bitwise not.  I understand it flips all the bits but it is not working how I expect in C++.  Here is the relevent code.

```
letter = 'A';  // dec = 65   hex = 0x41   binary = 0100 0001
cout << endl << "Bitwise NOT" << endl;
cout << "Letter: " << letter << " = " << insertSpaces(toBinary(letter)) << endl;
int notletter = ~letter;
cout << "~Letter: " << notletter << endl;


string insertSpaces(string binary)
// insert spaces into a binary number string for readability
{
    int pos = 4;
    int len = binary.length();

    while (pos < len)
    {
        binary.insert(pos, " ");
        pos = pos + 5;   // 5 because it includes space
        len++;           // space makes length longer
    }
    return binary;
}

string toBinary(int letter)
{
    string result = "";
    while (letter > 0)
    {
        result = toString(letter % 2) + result;
        letter /= 2;
    }
    int rem = result.length() % 4;
    if (rem > 0)
    {
        int zeros = 4 - rem;
        for (int i = 0; i < zeros; i++)
            result = "0" + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the output.

```
Bitwise NOT
Letter: A = 0100 0001
~Letter: -66
```

The answer should be 190 or 1011 1110 in binary so why did I get -66?
I am using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Pretty much the same confusion as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274753/bitwise-complement-operator

Comment: I don't do C++ at all so I can't tell you specifically how to fix it, but 10111110=-66 if your char is signed and 190 if it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Use an unsigned integer rather than a signed one. The reason you got a negative number is because most computers today use [two's complement](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

This is what your data looks like before and after the bitwise not:

```
before     | after
0100 0001  | 1011 1110
```

(actually there's probably 32 bits there since you're using an `int` and not a `char`; the best type to use here would probably be `uint8_t`)

In two's complement, a number is negative if the most significant bit is 1. After the not, it is. In two's compliment, to negate a number, you take the bitwise not and add 1. If you take `1011 1110` and invert it, you get `0100 0001`. Now you add one, resulting in `0100 0010`. If you convert that to decimal, you get 66. Add the minus since the first bit was one, and you get -66, the unexpected value.

Comment: Note that the result then will be _much_ larger than the `190` he's expecting - unless his platform has 8bit `int`s (which is not possible AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a signed number in [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The value has exceeded the largest positive value (127) and wrapped to the negative space.

You can print it as an unsigned character/integer (i.e., `(unsigned int)notletter` or `static_cast<unsigned int>(notletter)`).